# Errors in Wordpress Dashboard: Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to fix this error that I'm getting from my WordPress admin panel

```
Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Cookie\Jar.php on line 63

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Cookie\Jar.php on line 73

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Cookie\Jar.php on line 89

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Cookie\Jar.php on line 102

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Cookie\Jar.php on line 111

Deprecated: http_build_query(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($numeric_prefix) of type string is deprecated in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Transport\cURL.php on line 345

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Utility\CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 40

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Utility\CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 51

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Utility\CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 68

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Utility\CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 82

Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\lukas\Local Sites\pidolapalabraweb\app\public\wp-includes\Requests\Utility\CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 91
```

Note that I don't want to hide the error but fix it. Anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: All the errors appear to be coming from core WP files - so this is nothing you should try to fix manually in the first place; you should update your WP to a current version, or at least one compatible with your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that this is part of the core WP files.  Backup and update.
However, one of the things to check is that your version of PHP is "correct" (matches what's expected), as this may cause the WP update to fail.  If there is a discrepancy, this will require your hosting team to fix.
Go to Tools > Site Health > Info > Server for the details.